# How to find out in Inkscape which fonts are used in specific locations for imported PDFs?

Tags: inkscape, fonts, pdf

I use Inkscape to extract images and identify fonts from PDF files. I recall in an older version of Inkscape I could click on a piece of text in Inkscape and it would tell me the font name used for that text. At the moment, using the most recent stable Inkscape 1.3, when I click on different texts it only tells me "sans-serif". I know, however, that it is a named font - I just don't know which one or why Inkscape does not directly identify it to me any more.

I can see a list of fonts used in the PDF in the "PDF Import Settings" dialog, and also in the "Text and Font" tab, but I can't see any way of getting Inkscape to identify which font is used in specific places the document. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Inkscape 1.3, in the PDF import dialog, in the Internal Import tab, under Fonts, choose the option that says "keep missing fonts' names".  Note however that missing fonts will actually be replaced by a substitute, but the font name should remain, even if you don't have the font installed locally.

To see the font name, select the text tool, and click in the text field. The font name should be visible in the controls bar along the top.

Note that doing this will likely mess up the entire document with replacement fonts. But there would be nothing to stop you from opening the document again, and using the default font option "Draw missing fonts". You could keep both versions of the document open while you work.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I did try "keep missing font's names" before but not using the text tool. In a previous version of Inkscape I could just use the selector tool, click on text and in the status bar it said `Text (Century Schoolbook, 12 pt)` whereas now it always says `Text (sans-serif, 12 pt)` regardless of font - even if it's a serif font.

Comment: @authentictech - yes the behaviour seems to have changed. Not sure why, but the ordinary Select tool does not seem to work for this now. It could potentially be a bug. You may want to report it.

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat Reader tells you which fonts are included in a pdf file and it's free.

Can't comment on Inkscape but as it's open-source the best option might be to try to run a copy of the old version, maybe in a VM, separate disk partition or spare computer.

Comment: In the question text, I mention that I can see which fonts are included using Inkscape. I've edited the question title to avoid any misunderstanding.